# SSRS - Multiple data with distinct value

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I have table for continent and for country:

[image]

what i'm trying to do is put all of the data in 1 row like this:

[image]

Comment: are both country and continent tables or fields of one table?

Comment: They are in the same table, i used left join in the dataset. but whenever i'm trying to display all the data only the last country is appearing. in this case when i try to display the data it only displaying as

Comment: They are from the same Dataset.

Comment: is it possible to do this on SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Insert a table with one row detail using country, right click on country , move down to Add Group, select row group / parent group. Tablix group properties will appear, select "continent" in the group by box.